# Timer APIs in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, settimeout, setinterval

Would a Nodejs instance scale with enormous usage of setInterval and setTimeout APIs? I have a use case where my NodeJS server needs to keep a timer for some activity going on at the client and if the total time lapsed is above a configurable time, then we push a message. From my understanding, any asynchronous task like ( timers or xhr ) are taken care by a background thread and once the event is done, then it gets pushed to main JS thread. If I create, for instance, 1000 timers at once, would that make my node process slow assuming many threads would be created the NodeJS

Comment: Probably find most of your answer here: [How many concurrent setTimeouts before performance issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276583/how-many-concurrent-settimeouts-before-performance-issues/38277310#38277310).  Your assumption that each timer is a new thread is not correct.

Comment: Probably best to implement a Promise based timer, which are non-blocking async threads.

Comment: @teachtyler timers are non blocking async by nature in JavaScript, right?

Comment: Also you can check into cron npm, https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: http://latentflip.com/loupe/   Test the event loop