# Loopback/express marking items for deletion after a time period

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a model `Item` which stores user items. This model has a field `endDate` at which the instances have to be marked for deletion by setting `expired` field to true. Is there some way I can do this in loopback/express automatically? I am using `postgresql` as database.

I can think of following 2 ways but I don't think they are the best solutions for this problem:

1) Using `setTimeout` I can call a function which would mark the items for deletion. This solution is not at all scalable as it is not `stateless` and if there are multiple instances of `node` running, this would cause issues.

2) Use `redis` database and for each item create a key in `redis` with expire time. `redis` will automatically call a function when the timer expires and I can delete the item then. This I think is scalable as this is `stateless`.

Is there a more efficient solution to this?

**Edit**

I want to notify the user also as soon as the item expires. So, I would need a function call to happen as soon as expiration happens. So setting expireAt key and running a cleanup utility at intervals, will not be of much help here.

Comment: Why not set an expired field in the database for each item.  They, you can periodically run a cleanup algorithm that queries for any items that have an expired value beyond some threshold and you can then remove them.  The state is entirely stored in the database so it will work just fine with clustering as any server in the cluster can run the cleanup code.

Comment: Thanks. That is an option but actually I want to notify the user also as soon as it expires (I am using websockets for that) .That is why I need a function call to happen when it expired.

Comment: Then you should add that requirement to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is scalable provided the scalability/performance [advise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276583/how-many-concurrent-settimeouts-before-performance-issues) is followed. The issue here is that `setTimeout` approach is not durable e.g. the functionality will be broken for some users if the server/container that hosts Express reboots. The other issue is that it will not work if you have multiple Express instances.

In case there is one Express instance using Redis will change neither scalability nor durability unless you enable Redis persistence to survive restarts/reboots or unless you use more than one Redis node.

In case there are multiple Express instances using Redis is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [operation hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html) like `access` to launch a function that would query the model to find the newly expired items.